# Create Rounded corners Hexagon ImageView shape in Android

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

[image: Hexagon Imageview]

I want rounded corners as shown in above image. How to create this type of hexagone in android. I try many this but its not work like i want.

I try bellow code for do that but in it I just get Hexagon but not like i want.

```
public class HexagonImageView extends ImageView {

private Path hexagonPath;
private Path hexagonBorderPath;
private float radius;
private Bitmap image;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private Paint paint;
private BitmapShader shader;
private Paint paintBorder;
private int borderWidth = 5;

public HexagonImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

public HexagonImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public HexagonImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paintBorder = new Paint();
    setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
    paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
    paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

    hexagonPath = new Path();
    hexagonBorderPath = new Path();

}

public void setRadius(float r) {
    this.radius = r;
    calculatePath();
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)  {
    this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)  {
    if (paintBorder != null)
        paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

    this.invalidate();
}

private void calculatePath() {

float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radius / 2);
float centerX = viewWidth/2;
float centerY = viewHeight/2;

hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - radius/2);
hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + radius/2);
hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);

float radiusBorder = radius - borderWidth;    
float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3) * radiusBorder / 2);

hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - radiusBorder/2);
hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + radiusBorder/2);
hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);

this.invalidate();
}

private void loadBitmap()  {
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

    if (bitmapDrawable != null)
    image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
super.onDraw(canvas);

loadBitmap();

// init shader
if (image != null) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    canvas.drawPath(hexagonBorderPath, paintBorder);
    canvas.drawPath(hexagonPath, paint);
    canvas.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
}

}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

radius = height / 2 - borderWidth;

calculatePath();

setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)   {
int result = 0;
int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)  {
    result = specSize;
}
else {
    result = viewWidth;
}

return result;
}

private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)  {
int result = 0;
int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
    result = specSize;
}
else {
    result = viewHeight;
}

return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This library can may be help you ?

=> https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview